# Swift WkWebView createWebArchiveData confused on return type

Tags: wkwebview

I am trying to capture the content displayed in a webview (not the source, which is a bunch of javascripts). I'm hoping wkwebview's createWebArchiveData is the right method.

So, where I am getting confused is what gets returned from the call.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    
    webView.createWebArchiveData(completionHandler: { (result) in
        
    })
```

the docs say result is Result<data, error>. I did a type(of:) on it and the log printed Result<data, error>...thanks Apple...

when I printed result I got:

```
success(5990802 bytes)
```

thought maybe it was a tuple, but result.0 threw an error...

```
Value of type 'Result<Data, Error>' has no member '0'
```

tried to convert data to string...that didn't work...

tried to unarchive it, that failed as well.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Result<Data, Error>' to expected argument type 'Data
```

so, any help would be appreciated. I need what is displayed on the screen, not the source code (in case I am going about this wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You have get() method that will return data if result is success, less code for sure :)

```
if let data = try? result.get() {
               //do something with data 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The Result object is an enum with two cases success and failure. You would read the value (in this case because it is Data) like so:

```
webView.createWebArchiveData(completionHandler: { (result) in
        
        //var strResult = String(utf8String: result)
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
            print(str)
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    })
```